# R: Extract unique values in one column match by values in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to print string from df1 if it does not exist in df2

```
df1 <- data.frame(One = c("userID1", "userID5", "userID9"))
df2 <- data.frame(Two = c("userID2", "userID4", "userID1", "userID7"))
```

I would like to print string from df1 if it does not exist in df2

```
Output <- data.frame(Two = c("userID5", "userID9"))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!df2, on = .(One = Two)]
       One
1: userID5
2: userID9
```

Comment: Thank you, dear. Accepted. Have a good day

Answer (score 7):

You could use `dplyr`'s `anti_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(One = c("userID1", "userID5", "userID9"))
df2 <- data.frame(Two = c("userID2", "userID4", "userID1", "userID7"))

df1 %>% 
  anti_join(df2, by = c("One" = "Two"))
```

returns

```r
      One
1 userID5
2 userID9
```

Answer (score 5):

Or simply

```r
df1 <- data.frame(One = c("userID1", "userID5", "userID9"))
df2 <- data.frame(Two = c("userID2", "userID4", "userID1", "userID7"))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
df1 %>%
  filter(!One %in% df2$Two)
#>       One
#> 1 userID5
#> 2 userID9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>